# Forcing Google Chrome POST/GET with JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome

I'm cross posting this question here. After a few days of it being unanswered, I realize the core question may be more of a web dev question, rather than Wordpress.

My original question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78037/wp-click-track-plugin-help

Details:

(Note: The wordpress plugin developer has admittedly given up on this plugin, so I'm on my own.)

Plugin location: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-click-track/
Files in question within plugin: ajax.js and click-tracker.php

I've been using WP-Click-Track plugin for a few years now and it works great. The basis of the plugin is to find `a href's` within the post, and rewrite them with a little javascript. When the user clicks the link, the javascript reports to the plugin, which saves the link, the title and a count into a MySQL table. Pretty straight forward.

Even after a few years of undevelopment, the plugin continues to work great with Firefox and IE. It seems with the latest round of Chrome updates however, the plugin is not tracking them, unless the link (internal or external) contains `target="_blank"`. This is fine for externally facing links, but I don't want to have internal links open up in a new window. That's annoying to the user.

I can see in the JavaScript that the plugin is asking browsers to do a `POST` for `XMLHttpRequest`, but after looking at my Apache logs, it appears as though Chrome is performing a `GET` for links that do not contain `target="_blank"`.

*This is where I think stackoverflow comes in:* Is there a way (through another JavaScript applet?) to force Chrome to always do a POST so that those links are tracked?

Comment: What does it show in the network tab from the chrome developer's console?

Comment: When I click an internal re-written link, I'm seeing a lot of `GET` in the network tab. When I click an external link, I see a lot of `GET` as well from the network tab. However, my apache logs show the external link was a `POST` to the internal tracker script, and then sends out to the site.

Comment: Your penultimate paragraph is quite confusing. The XHR implementation won't change the request method. The GET request must be coming from something else ([pre-rendering](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender) maybe).

Another thing is, Chrome will abort any AJAX request, sent or not, if the user is leaving the page. If AJAX is called during the click handler of a link, then most likely it will abort even before any HTTP request is sent.

Comment: I'm not a web developer by trade. This is my part-time hobby. I know enough to know what's wrong and can usually tinker enough to get it band-aided together. Thus, my description of said problem may not be in the correct jargon. This is why I've linked the plugin and referenced the files in question. To the best of my knowledge, when a user clicks a link, JavaScript is "asking" for a POST. The POST goes to `/?wp_click_tracked=`, which logs it with a few items of interest, and the browser continues to the link. Appears Chrome uses GET and it is failing. Firefox/IE both continue to work.